# Double Saving after AJAX-Call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

i have a weird problem by saving a record with AJAX and Rails. I want to save a record by using drag'n drop with jQuery Sortable (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists). The saving is working fine... nearly. the same record, which should be saved by dragging an element from one list to another, is saved twice :( i have no idea why. maybe someone can help me...

**view/dev_languages/new.html.haml**

```
=title_header(t('.your_qualifications'))
#dev_languages
  .container_12
    #dev_language_type_btns
      %span#application_btn= 'Application'
      %span#web_btn= 'Web'
      %span#mobile_btn= 'Mobile'

  .container_12
    .grid_6
      #application_dev_languages
        =render @application_dev_languages
      #web_dev_languages
        =render @web_dev_languages
      #mobile_dev_languages
        =render @mobile_dev_languages
    .grid_6
      %h3= "Skill Wall"
      %ul#skill_wall.connectedSortable
        %li= "blubb"
        %li= "bla"
```

**assets/javascripts/dev_languages.js.coffee**

```
$("#languages, #skill_wall").sortable(
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  update: ->
    alert "www"
    $.ajax
      url: "/has_dev_languages"
      type: "post"
      #processData: false
      data:
        creator_id: 1
        creator_type: "Expert"
        application_type_id: 1
        dev_language_id: 1
  ).disableSelection()
```

**controllers/has_dev_languages_controller.rb**

```
class HasDevLanguagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @has_dev_languages = HasDevLanguage.create(
        :creator_id       => params[:creator_id],
        :creator_type     => params[:creator_type],
        :application_type_id => params[:application_type_id],
        :dev_language_id  => params[:dev_language_id]
    )
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.js
    end
  end
```

end

**controllers/dev_languages_controller.rb**

```
class DevLanguagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :find_base_data

  private

    def find_base_data
      @application_dev_languages  = DevLanguage.where(:application_type_id => '1')
      @web_dev_languages          = DevLanguage.where(:application_type_id => '2')
      @mobile_dev_languages       = DevLanguage.where(:application_type_id => '3')
    end
```

end

**view/has_dev_languages/create.js.erb**

```
window.location.reload();
```

**Server-Log**

```
Started POST "/has_dev_languages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 12:18:27 +0200
Processing by HasDevLanguagesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"creator_id"=>"1", "creator_type"=>"Expert", "application_type_id"=>"1", "dev_language_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `has_dev_languages` (`application_type_id`, `created_at`, `creator_id`, `creator_type`, `dev_language_id`, `job_posting_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '2013-08-03 10:18:27', 1, 'Expert', 1, NULL, '2013-08-03 10:18:27')
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered has_dev_languages/create.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started POST "/has_dev_languages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 12:18:27 +0200
Processing by HasDevLanguagesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"creator_id"=>"1", "creator_type"=>"Expert", "application_type_id"=>"1", "dev_language_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `has_dev_languages` (`application_type_id`, `created_at`, `creator_id`, `creator_type`, `dev_language_id`, `job_posting_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '2013-08-03 10:18:27', 1, 'Expert', 1, NULL, '2013-08-03 10:18:27')
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered has_dev_languages/create.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)


Started GET "/has_dev_languages/__meta_request/d7377832adbf2d9a0460a0a4426b5d2f.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 12:18:28 +0200


Started GET "/de/dev_languages/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 12:18:29 +0200
Processing by DevLanguagesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"de"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  DevLanguage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `dev_languages`.* FROM `dev_languages` WHERE `dev_languages`.`application_type_id` = 1
  Rendered dev_languages/_dev_language.html.haml (0.1ms)
  DevLanguage Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `dev_languages`.* FROM `dev_languages` WHERE `dev_languages`.`application_type_id` = 2
  Rendered dev_languages/_dev_language.html.haml (0.1ms)
  DevLanguage Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `dev_languages`.* FROM `dev_languages` WHERE `dev_languages`.`application_type_id` = 3
  Rendered dev_languages/_dev_language.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered dev_languages/new.html.haml within layouts/application (6.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_flashes.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (0.4ms)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered modals/forms/_login_expert_form.html.haml (12.0ms)
  Rendered modals/_login_expert.html.haml (12.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 205ms (Views: 202.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/has_dev_languages/__meta_request/a9d0157927d47455f5af2be3593404c5.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 12:18:29 +0200


Started GET "/de/dev_languages/new/__meta_request/fa0990fcfbf1ee313d620ed95e7aa3d4.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 12:18:29 +0200
```

Please help me. I'm sitting here for 3 days with this problem! :( :( :(

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved! I have to add `stop: (event, ui) ->` instead of `update: ->` in Coffee-Script. Finally! =)